# How to add External Content Types?

Tags: content-type, external-content-type, data

[image]

Hi All,

I am currently having an issue with trying to add External Content Types. My error is in the pic provided. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you facing this error on SP2013 onpremise?

Comment: Hey Anuja,

Yes Im using Sharepoint 2013 onpremise

Comment: What's the type of the data web part that you use ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have the Business Data Connectivity Service Application created in Central Admin
2. In Central Admin -> Services on Server and make sure the Business Data Connectivity Service is started.
3. Application Management  -> Manage service applications. delete the "Managed Metadata Service" from the lists.
4. Again add the "Managed Metadata Service" from Service Applications -> New.

These steps should resolve your issue.